# Wait until all elements have been parsed from SOAP request

Tags: ios, swift, soap, nsurlsession

I am currently trying to implement a feature in Swift that sends a query that returns multiple elements. My queries are working, however it seems like the program does not wait for all of the elements (or any, sometimes) to be parsed - often making my labels empty. How can I make the program wait for the response to be completely finished before it moves on.

The current setup I currently have is :

sendQuery(query)
//do next function to update labels

sendQuery is a function that sets up the SOAP request and starts the NSURLSession, the response is then parsed by the XML parser and sets string values based on what the currentElement is.

I have no previous experience with swift so I'm not sure what direction I should be looking in.

Edit: The SOAP session request with the completion handler looks like:

```
func sendQuery()
{
 //setup request params

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
        parser.delegate = self
        if parser.parse() {
            print(self.currentElementName)
        }
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error: " + error!.description)
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

edit2:

I have changed everything to the following: 
This is in my main viewController:

```
NetConn.getItemInfo(query, withCompletionClosure: {(itemInfo: [String]) in
                    self.itemInfo = itemInfo
                })
```

While this is in a separate NetworkConnections file:

```
func getroomInfo(query: String, withCompletionClosure completionClosure: (roomInfo: [String])->())// -> [String]
{
    //Setup SOAP request information
    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
        parser.delegate = self
        if parser.parse() {
            print(self.currentElementName)
        }
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("Error: " + error!.description)
        }
        completionClosure(roomInfo: self.roomInfo)
    }).resume()

}
```

This does correctly wait until the batch of responses is finished, however - I'm finding that if I try to print the information immediately after the call it is unchanged still. It looks like a thread is taking the call and running it while the original thread keeps running through the main block of code. How can I prevent this from happening?

....edit3: I believe adding

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                //ui stuff
            })
```

into the completion handler in the main viewcontroller call is going to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never wait, instead you need to restructure the code to use a completion block aka completion handler implemented using a closure, such as this (pseudo code not compilable code, I can't remember closure syntax off the top of my head)

```
sendQueryWithCompletionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
  // this is where the completion handler code goes
})
```

That's one approach, another might be instead of using a completion closure for the sendQuery() method to broadcast a notification when the data is available and for the calling code to listed for that broadcast.
Which is more appropriate depends on the overall design and requirements.

You need to learn about asynchronous execution of code.

(block is objective-c terminology, closure is Swift terminology for the same concept)

Comment: I have tried using a completion handler in my creation of the session, which did not work.  
`let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
            parser.delegate = self
            if parser.parse() {
                print(self.currentElementName)
            }
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error: " + error!.description)
            }
        })
        task.resume()` 
 Should I be using this on the sendQuery call instead?

Comment: Can you post that code in the original question, formatted. Its not possible to digest it like that.

Comment: What will happen is a) sendQuery() gets called b) do next function to update labels gets called c) completionHandler() gets called. You still haven't moved b) into a completion handler. You can invoke a completion handler to execute b) within the completion handler of the NSURLconnection. Or in your existing completion handler broadcast a notification. Your view controller listens to the notification and when it fires b) executes, which has been moved into a new method of the view controller.

Comment: In other words you added a completion handler between sendQuery() and NSURLSession. But you additionally need a completion handler between the code that calls sendQuery() and sendQuery().

Comment: I'll look into that further. Thank you for your help so far.